# Some necessary words are filtered in question title

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, title, filtering

Yesterday I was trying to post a question on Stack Overflow about the 'halting problem', which had the word 'problem' in the title. So I was not able post the question. It said that the title cannot contain the word 'problem'. 'problem' is a necessary word, it should not be filtered.

Comment: This shall from now on be referred to as the "Halting Issue".